# ZSH extends bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

It's possible to make ZSH extends bash autocompletion? Bash can autocomplete almost every command in the system, and in ZSH i always need to enable a plugin for it.

Here is an example (ignore the warnings, are from custom scripts that don't work in bash)

[image: Bash autocompletion]

Answer (score 1):

`java`'s `--version` option seems to be undocumented. The documented one is `-version`. Try `java -v<Tab>`.

`java --v<Tab>` should also suggest `-version` if you enabled approximation/corrections in the completion configuration:

```
$ java --vTab
Completing corrections
-verbose:class  -verbose  -- print class information
-verbose:gc               -- print gc information
-verbose:jni              -- print JNI information
-version                  -- print version
```

See `compinstall` for an easy way to configure it.

See `info zsh bashcompinit` for how to use bash completion functions within zsh, but note that bash completions are generally inferior to zsh ones. You'd only want to use it for the cases where completers have been written for `bash` but not `zsh`.

Comment: the java -v was just an example. Most of the commands don't autocomplete in ZSH, except the ones i enable the plugin. In bash, almost every command automatically suggests autocompletions, i wanted this behavior in ZSH.

Comment: @Maxwells.c, you may want to provide with a real example that exhibits the problem. zsh programmed completion predates bash's by decades. bash doesn't come with completers, you generally get them either from the bash-completion project or sometimes shipped alongside the commands they're meant to complete.

Comment: i couldn't find one now. Before, some common ones such as *apt* and *snap* didn't work, but i think the bashcompinit may did the trick.

Comment: @Maxwells.c, completers for Debian `apt-*` commands were added to `zsh` in [1999](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02669.html) and for the newer Debian `apt` command in [2014](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00321.html). Both a bash and zsh completer for Ubuntu `snap` are supplied by Ubuntu as part of the `snapd` package. See `dpkg -L snapd | grep complet`